# Scene with PNGs not working in VSE

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, transparency, scene

I am quite new to blender and trying to put together a simple motion typo with Video editing.

For the typo I set a scene of PNGs with alpha, and animated them.
In the Video sequence Editor I edited the rest of the video, but I only see a grey rectangle when I add the scene to the VSE.

How can I make the scene visible ? What have I done wrong ?

[image: this is what I see]

Thanks for the answers !

Comment: Try unchecking OpenGL preview in the Scene strip properties.

Comment: Would this answer still apply today? (2.79b)I don't see any preview choices, let alone for OpenGL. Anywhere, let alone in the Scene strip properties.